# Pointer_stringify is returning garbled text

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I have have the following `lib.jslib` file

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  IsGuestUser: function (objectName, objectMethodName) {
    gamesmart.user.isGuest(function (result) {
      console.log(Pointer_stringify(objectName), Pointer_stringify(objectMethodName), result);
      gameSmartGameInstance.SendMessage(Pointer_stringify(objectName), Pointer_stringify(objectMethodName), result);
    });
  }
});
```

Which gets called from here:

```
namespace GameSmart {
  public class User : API {
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    public static extern void IsGuestUser(string objectName, string objectMethodName);

    public static void IsGuest(string objectName, string objectMethodName) {
      IsGuestUser(objectName, objectMethodName);
    }
  }
}
```

And is initiated like so:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
  void Start() {
    GameSmart.User.IsGuest("GameSmart", "OnIsGuest");
  }
}
```

As seen above I pass `GameSmart` and `OnIsGuest` to the JavaScript, and when it gets to the JavaScript I call `Pointer_stringify()` on both of the values.

When converted and logged, I get the following output: `0Zހ` and `ﳀ�` I should have gotten `GameSmart` and `OnIsGuest` back but I didn't what is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the fix for this was to move `Pointer_stringify` outside of the anonymous function so It looks like this:

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  IsGuestUser: function (objectName, objectMethodName) {
    var jsObjectName = Pointer_stringify(objectName);
    var jsObjectMethodName = Pointer_stringify(objectMethodName);
    gamesmart.user.isGuest(function (result) {
      gameSmartGameInstance.SendMessage(jsObjectName, jsObjectMethodName, result);
    });
  }
});
```